# Scania 4 series Opticruise gearbox problems

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, scania

I am having issues with the Scanias. I have a 4 series Bus (K124) Opticruise. These are 8 speed 4 Low / 4 High Range.

We are having an intermittent issue with banging into gear. This will only happen in the bottom 4 gears (low) Generally under light load or when going down a light grade Will occur after gearbox is warm.

You can drive it hard with heavy revs and it seems to help it. I have changed the Master Cylinder Oil - there was some metal there but nothing huge.

I don't want to take the box out and put it back and maybe have the same issue again. Any ideas as to the cause here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Having metal in your oil is never a good thing - it means some part of your system has had bits of metal ground off it. Gearboxes that get ground down tend do show a range of symptoms, and banging into gear or popping out of gear are two rather common ones.

Taking the gearbox out will let you visually inspect the gears - this will let you see if they are worn or damaged.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with your splitter or backsection part of the gearbox/transmission that is the section where the high and low sleeve is situated,also check that the air of the truck dont push to much air pressure to the valve that splits between the range as the force will cause the sleeve and synchro,s to wear out quickly,if it is so put a air restrictor on the bring the air pressure down a bit on the valve side

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thankyou for your response. Whole range change unit and planetary gears at the back of the box have been changed. They all had some minor wear. Still doing it, mainly changing gears around corners and down hill.